# How do I turn this javscript code for a randomized multiple choice code into a set order?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making this educational resource for teacher to teach about the human immune system and I am stuck on how I can change this code so that there could an order that I want the questions to be displayed since the questions are randomized right now. There is another css web formatting code but that's just button styles and page layout. The code is below:

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '22', correct: false }
    },
{
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '22', correct: false }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: "how I can change this code so that there could an order that I want the questions to be displayed" plese elaborate

Comment: @StefanAvramovic right now if I start the quiz, the questions are not given in a specific order but randomized. I want the questions to appear in the same order everytime. How do I do this?

Comment: Step one: Do you recognize what part of the above code does the randomization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
```

to

```
shuffledQuestions = questions.slice()
```

Comment: thx I'll accept this answer... just waiting on timer